# password_hash с разной солью на разных страницах. Возможно исправить?

Tags: php, хеширование

Столкнулся с проблемой. На странице входа / регистрации регистрируюсь, пароль хешируется, можно выйти и зайти заново с этим паролем. На странице профиля есть возможность смены пароль, притом меняется он тем-же password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT), но после выхода залогинеться уже не получается, т.к. результат password_hash в логине уже не соответствует результату password_hash в базе данных. Есть ли способы это исправить? Спасибо!

Comment: а вы где пароль-то меняете? только в базе и надо. только в одном месте должен лежать хэш текущего пароля

Comment: В базе и меняю, в той-же самой ячейке, где и был предыдущий и с использованием той-же функции

Answer (score 1):

Результат нового `password_hash` для одного и того же пароля не будет совпадать, поскольку соль каждый раз генерируется случайно (если вы не задали её в параметрах функции). Для проверки пароля следует использовать функцию `password_verify`

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php

Comment: password_verify, к сожалению, тоже false возвращает.

Comment: не могли бы вы код добавить, что вы передаете в password_verify

Comment: надо передавать пароль пользователя, введенный в форму и хеш, сохраненный в БД

Comment: так и делаю. беру хеш из БД

Comment: $user = R::findOne('users','email = ?', array($_POST['login']));

  if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $user->password)){
   echo json_encode(array($user->id,'ok'), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: дело может быть в том, что они захешированы под разной солью?

Comment: @МирейАров хэш, созданный `password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` содержит в себе и соль и алгоритм хеширования. Поэтому password_verify должна проверить правильно

Comment: @МирейАров `R::findOne('users','email = ?', array($_POST['login']))` а точно у вас из базы получает по емейлу? Проверьте вообще этот запрос возвращает пользователя? И какой хэш он возвращает

Comment: ну и возможно хеш неправильно сохраняется (например обрезается по длинне)